# Generate a url for a specific text or area in a pdf (like a bookmark)

Tags: pdf

So that the link can be used in some external applications, and users in that application can click the link and navigate to that specific location (text or area) in the pdf.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are several different URL # (fragment) constructs that were introduced by  Adobe  for use with their web browser PDf viewer plug-in. The current accessible list is at https://pdfobject.com/pdf/pdf_open_parameters_acro8.pdf

Many newer competing PDF enabled browsers may use similar, but there is no guarantee one URL.pdf#Fits all. Most will respect #page=number&zoom view or fit but it is very variable, thus you need to check each feature across browsers.

Important to switch off any PDF remember my view settings

[image]

For your previous request using Bookmarks can be unreliable (as can the comments ID) unless you are using Acrobat and can check the bookmark function. By far the more reliable may be the use of zoom at a scroll location so here using MS Edge:-

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" file:///C:/Users/.../Desktop/CEI-PID-Sample-Rev4annotsC.pdf#zoom=300,200,200
```

[image]

I support SumatraPDF however its browser plug-in whilst still functional is way past EOL thus unsupported, it had a limited support for those fragments even though the CLI was recently extended for some Acrobat /Action commands.

However related to your desire the one single portable EXE can jump to well formed text blocks. Here I call "V 4508" in a fairly similar fashion

```
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\SandBox\apps\Graphics\CEI-PID-Sample-Rev4annotsC.pdf" -zoom 300 -search "V 4508"
```

[image]

And if I press A then the text will be highlighted for comments

[image]